# Xcode console Warning: number tree nodes contain overlapping ranges:

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I get "Warning: number tree nodes contain overlapping ranges:"in my Xcode console.I really want to know why I get this warning.

thanks a lot!

Comment: Having same issue? Should I be worried?